# Upgrading an app to support iOS5, 6 and 7

Tags: design, ios

We are looking at an app that needs an upgrade. Currently it runs on iOS4, 5 & 6. The upgrade will move to iOS5, 6 & 7. It will also involve some UI changes and new features. I've been reading stuff on iOS7 and looking at things like auto-layout.

What we are trying to figure out is the best way to handle the differences between the various iOS versions. Auto-layout seems like a good idea, but it's not available on iOS 5. There are also API changes to consider between all 3 versions and other new features of iOS7.

So the questions:

1. How would you handle auto layout given iOS5 does not have it?
2. Are there any significant differences between the SDKs that you think would cause issues?
3. Would we be better off with separate code bases?

Comment: You'll have to decide if maintaining separate code bases or losing backward compatibility is worth the benefit of gaining the new features.

Comment: Take a look at: [Enabling auto layout in iOS 6 while remaining backwards compatible with iOS 5](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12537643/1394020).

Answer (score 1):

A couple different possibilities for a requirement to support both iOS 6 and 7.  One is to create two different sets of xib's, selected at runtime depending on the OS version of the device.  The other is to also detect the OS version at runtime, and run code to modify UI elements to their desired position and appearance options, specific to the current OS of the device.